# Model-View-Controller and application settings

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, settings

I am trying to create desktop Java Swing application according to **MVC** pattern.
Where should I put my application settings logic? Is it a part of view or model or controller?
For example: I want to save application window size and position to hard drive. I will use `DataOutputStream` to save them into external file.

Comment: I would say that it would be represent as part of the model and controller, which would affect the view...

Comment: Use `java.util.Preferences` instead of an external file; an example is cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513).